# Shrink flex-wrapped-children to fit parent container with wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a container of given size with unknown number of children (at the time of writting) with images that will be placed in rows in it. I experimented with flex container and have something like that:

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items:center;
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/4gacev6f/1/

This works reasonably well... until I added several more children:

Added more children objects: https://jsfiddle.net/4gacev6f/3/

I expected to have them wrapped in few lines, but they display in single line.

What can I do to force Flex container wrap the content, if there is some space to do so?

Comment: Don't specify flex properties on the flex items also you need to set a width or a height on the wrapped items depending on which direction is your flex container. https://jsfiddle.net/8kdjbL1t/

Comment: @ZohirSalak I wanted to avoid specifing width/height - even on your example, we have overflow instead of shrinking...

Comment: To the one voting to close it by not having enough information - I gave Minimal Working Example, desired output and actual output. Voting to closing it instead of asking for clarification if something is uncler, is a bit... overzelaous?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense not saying when wrapping should happen, that is not flexbox, By nature a flex container stretches infinitely along a single axis horizontally or vertically now if you don't tell when it should stop and wrap it will never happen, the width is defined by the images actual size which in this case is too big to fit within the dimensions you set. the overflow in the example because the container is too small for the width i set just to demonstrate.

Comment: @ZohirSalak So maybe not a flex solution? I need effect: content being fitted into div of given size, spanning more than one row if possible :)

Comment: it can be a flex solution, the problem has to do with the content, the images depend on the parent's width `max-width: 100%;` and the parent's width starts with 0 `flex-basis: 0` then the available space get distributed evenly now the elements will have a certain width but it's not real to some extent. If you keep adding elements at a certain point there will  be no more space to split and they will all be width 0.so you have to set a min width for your links or images because the content need to be known not dependent on it's parent.  I suggest you rethink your layout.